# the highlighting code bug with word-wrap

Tags: aptana, highlighting

i have a strange situation when hightlighting a code on word-wrap line, after 100 column (approx), the rest of the code is not coloring... there is white text...

if i insert a new line before white text, i have a this line highlighting.

so there is an option to increase the number of column of coloring code?

i have no probleme with "colorer", but i like php editor with aptana, so i think at a bug or hidden params ?

thanks.
joss

---

Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.2.1.201207261642

Answer (score 1):

To improve performance, there is a set value for the maximum number of columns before Aptana Studio editor turns off syntax coloring; the default value is 200. In the upcoming 3.2.2 release, it will provide a preference where you could customize the setting. Please see the relate [ticket](https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-4867) for reference.

Comment: Helps to know where we can find the preference. In Aptana Studio 3, it is under **Window -> Preferences -> Editors -> Syntax Coloring -> Max columns to color per line (-1 equals no max)**

Answer (score 0):

From v3.6.1 and above it is under **Windows > Preferences > Aptana Studio > Editors > Syntax Coloring -> Max columns to color per line (-1 equals no max)**